# Does polybase support having a table to represent a REST API?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019, polybase

I have customer information in a SQL server table, and the billing information is exposed via REST web api (with customer_id as parameter).

I am exploring using polybase to create the polybase table to represent the REST api, so that I can perform a JOIN between the customer table and REST web api.

Does polybase support this?